# Datetime format ignores am/pm?

Tags: datetime, string, formatting

Hi I am new to apex coding and am trying to parse a datetime and then later on in my program I am trying to convert it back into a string to query items.

For converting a string into a datetime I am using

```
String testDateString = '7/1/2015 1:30 PM';
DateTime testDate = DateTime.parse(sdate);
```

To convert the datetime back into a string I am using:

```
String convertedDate = testDate.formatGmt('yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'hh:mm:ss\'Z\'');
```

but this gives me the string
`2015-07-01T08:30:00.000Z`, which would be correct if the time was `7/1/2015 1:30 AM`

but I am expecting the string

```
2015-07-01T20:30:00.000Z.
```

Is there a reason why the `formatGmt` ignores the AM/PM? Am i doing something clearly wrong?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

You meant to use HH instead of hh. Lowercase hh returns only the 12-hour version of the hour, while using HH returns the zero-based 24-hour version of the hour. See Java's [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for more details.